# putty pagent window is not opening in my windows10 home version

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, webserver

i installed putty latest from the putty website. As i am working when i opened the peagent windows from the menu the windows of the peagent is not opening but the background process is running.

can any one please help me on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart System and Try to Run it at Startup:

Open Windows Explorer and navigate to:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Create a new Shortcut:

**Target:** "C:\tools\PuTTY\pageant.exe" id_rsa.ppk second.ppk third.ppk

**Start In:** "%HOMEPATH%.ssh"